# Yuphoria bricked and stuck in bootloop

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, boot-loop, bootloader, micromax-yu-yuphoria

My Android device YU Yuphoria is currently bricked and stuck in a bootloop. What I tried to do to cause this was that I first rooted the phone and installed TWRP. Then I installed Android Nougat on it, which was a success for the first few days but later got corrupted somehow. Now I'm stuck in a bootloop. Whenever I try to flash its stock ROM, it gives an error message "E: failed to mount". Infact, whatever I try to do in the Cynogen recovery mode, it gives this same error message. Can someone help me out of this?

Comment: So you need to flash it using a computer

Answer (score 1):

You should try flashing the phone using a computer.

- Download any firmware from this [link](https://firmwarefile.com/yu-yuphoria-yu5010a). - all are for **model Y5010a**, since you didn't mention which model.
- Unzip it and you'll find drivers,  flash files and the flashing instructions.
- Install drivers then follow the instructions for flashing.

Your​ phone should work fine now.

**UPDATE:**

I thought it would help if I reproduce all flashing steps here

- First download the Firmware, Flash tool and driver from above link
- Extract the file  (zip files) to desktop (You need to  install winrar software or 7zip to Extract)
- Open Driver folder and install Qualcomm_USB_Driver_Setup.exe file and wait until finish installation.
- Open QPST.WIN.2.7_Installer-00430.1 folder,  install setup.exe
- Now open QFIL from the "C:\Program Files\Qualcomm\QPST\bin" path.
- Tick on Flat Build option
- Go to Programmer Path and click on Browse.. button and choose prog_emmc_firehose_8916.mbn file
- Click on Load XML... button and choose rawprogram_unsparse.xml file and then choose patch0.xml file from the Firmware folder
- Now connect USB cable to the phone while holding​  volume up + volume down buttons.
- Drivers should be installed. Just Click on Download button on the programm and wait until finish procedure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138101/discussion-on-answer-by-esqmo-yuphoria-bricked-and-stuck-in-bootloop).